# App crashes after opening it from URL Scheme

Tags: swift, background, url-scheme

I have an app which can be opened using a custom URL scheme (`test://?name=johndoe`). This name is stored in a variable, `name`, in the `ViewController.swift`-file using the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any)` from `AppDelegate.swift`.

However, if I try to display this name in a label using an outlet which is defined in the same `ViewController.swift`-file after getting it from the URL, the app crashes.

I tried to instantiate the VC, I also tried to simply wait with putting it on the label a couple of seconds – both didn't worked. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us how you're parsing the name and sending it to the ViewController?

Comment: The outlets aren't set until the view controller is presented (i.e. in `viewDidLoad`). Set a property in the view controller to `name` from the URL and then in `viewDidLoad` set the outlet (label?) to contain the value of that property.

Comment: @Paolo I can't exactly get to it. Can you tell me a bit more in-depth on how to do this? :/